# Vim: How to use the control key as my local leader?

Tags: vim

After reading several posts here (and the help file inside Vim) I successfully set my local leader to comma using

```
let maplocalleader = ","
```

I was wondering if it's possible to use the control key as a local leader.

I tried

```
let maplocalleader = "<C>"
```

but now it doesn't work at all.  Can the control key be used as a local leader in VIM?
(Or the shift key?  Or the alt key?)

Answer (score 5):

No. Vim is unable to see modifier keys as actual keys so you can't use `ctrl`, `Shift` or `Alt` as `<leader>`.

Note that the leader key is not special in any way: only the variables `mapleader` and `maplocalleader` are.

```
let mapleader = ","
nnoremap <leader>x foobar
```

works like:

```
execute "nnoremap " . mapleader . "x foobar"
```

and is, *in fine*, exactly the same as:

```
nnoremap ,x foobar
```

So don't get too hung up on that `<leader>` business.

Answer (score 0):

You can't map a single key like `<c>` to a leader key, but you can make a combination like `<c-s>`. You do this by by pressing  to enter a special keycode and then . So what you type out is:
`let mapleader = "(Press control v)(press control s)"`